# jquery: if input field length is more than 0?

Tags: jquery, html, input

I am using the following jquery to change the colour of my border if the input length is more than 0.

for some reason the script works if i place it on my index.php page where my form is.

index.php:

```
<?php include 'jquery.php'; ?>

<form>
<input type="text" id="promo" />
</form>
```

script:

```
<script>
$("#promo").keypress(function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $("#promo").css("border", "1px solid #666666");
    }
});
</script>
```

however if i try to place the jquery in my jquery.php file it doesn't work? can someone please show me where i am going wrong with this?

Thanks,

Comment: add script tag in your jquery.php file or include between script tag

Comment: Noticed that the `<input>` has no value: `<input value="">`

Comment: @Paul `<input>`'s when rendered by the browser, have the `value` attribute automatically.  developers need not put it in there unless they want a pre-specified value `:)`

Comment: I did not know that ;-) But since you didn't mentioned it in your answer i thought that it might be indeed a default attribute when rendered.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely happening for one of two reasons (or possibly both):

1. You are including the `jquery.php` *before* the DOM element is rendered.
2. You are including the `jquery.php` *before* jQuery has been loaded.

My recommendation is that you put your `include 'jquery.php'` under the form, and possibly wrap it in a:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#promo").onkeypress....
});
```

Just to make sure that jQuery is ready, and the element is ready to be interacted with.

Also make sure that you are "indeed" loading jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
```

or externally

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```